# dovecotpw returns different hash when used the $ symbol

Tags: php, ssh, md5, dovecot

I tried in PHP via SSH to generate password with the command `dovecotpw`
and if the password contains the $ sign symbol than it generates different hash from the hash the dovecotpw generates in command line.

here is the line that generates the password:

```
echo $ssh->exec('dovecotpw -s CRAM-MD5 -p test$test');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remote shell is using the `$` to denote a shell variable. Escape the argument.

```
...('... \'test$test\'');
```

Comment: Yeah now I understand what is going on.. thank you I am going to accept your answer because problem solved